# Covariance of a random function

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose $X(s)=\int_0^1 G(s,t)\, dW(t)$, where $W(t)$ is Brownian motion, then what is the variance of $X(s)$ and the covariance of $X(s)$ and $X(r)$.

Note that this is not the usual Ito integral question, since integration is over a fixed integral. $X$ is a random function obtained by smoothing a realization of Brownian motion over $[0,1]$

Comment: This really depends on the measurability hypotheses on $G$.

Comment: OK, but let's assume that the necessary conditions hold. I'm particularly interested in the case where G(s,t) is a Green's function for a a linear differentiable operator, so you're talking about functions that are based on the solution set of $Lf=0$ for a linear differential operator $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is deterministic, this is very much "the usual Ito integral question", actually the very definition shows that, for every $s$ and $r$,
$$
E(X(s)X(r))=\int_0^1G(s,t)\,G(r,t)\,\mathrm dt.
$$